# Convert JSON String to List of Object

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to convert a `JSON` String to a List of `Objects` (Attachments), but when I try to do so I get a `NPE`.

```
 List<Attachment> attachments = new ArrayList<>();

 Timber.d("EMPTY------>"+dbResponse.get(i).getAttachments().isEmpty());
 Timber.d("SIZE------>"+dbResponse.get(i).getAttachments().length());

for(...){ 

 if(dbResponse.get(i).getAttachments().length()!=0) //has attachments?
   {
         //transforms the string into list of attachments
         Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Attachment>>(){}.getType();
         attachments = new Gson().fromJson(dbResponse.get(i).getAttachments(), listType);

         for(int j=0; j<attachments.size() ; j++) {...}
}
```

I get the error on the for os the `attachments.size()`.
The error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                 at com.rd.ch.repository.AppDataManager.lambda$findAllMessages$1$AppDataManager(AppDataManager.java:177)
                                                                 at com.rdev.chatapp.repository.AppDataManager$$Lambda$1.apply(Unknown Source)
```

The timber are returning `EMPTY->false` and `Size->4`.
What am I doing wrong on the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to read `dbResponse.get(i).getAttachments()` as json but looks like it's not a valid json and `Gson().fromJson` returns `null`.

Print out the `dbResponse.get(i).getAttachments()` and you'll see what you want to read as Json.